# Compatibility between ERC-1400 and ERC-1643

Tags: solidity, tokens

How does a contract supporting both [ERC-1400](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1411) and [ERC-1643](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1643) should be written as their functions `setDocument` don't have the same arguments and their `getDocument` don't return the same types?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity allows two functions with the same name and different parameters.

They will have different signatures so the client will call the correct one.

Note: The return values are not considered in the signature. A contract cannot have two functions with identical parameters and different return types.

Comment: In the case of getDocument they have the same arguments but don't return the same types. The compiler shows "DeclarationError: Function with same name and arguments defined twice.".

Comment: @Sony You are correct, return types are not part of the signature. I modified my answer to mention that. So unless they fix one of the interfaces a contract cannot implement both at the same time.